# Is it possible to predict sentiments using supervised deep learning method?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, sentiment-analysis

I created a corpus of 30,000 headlines. I want to predict the sentiments of these headlines using advanced supervised machine learning (deep learning) methods such as RNN, LSTM, or DNN.

**My question is:** Is it possible to train and test a deep learning model with any labeled datasets such as IMDB movie review, amazon review, or yelp review.
For example, suppose we train and test the IMDB movie reviews dataset with RNN which gives us a 92% f1 score.

Then, can I input my unlabeled dataset (30,000 headlines) and predict their sentiments with this trained and tested model?

The reason for asking this question is that I found many blogs and tutorial with code that uses deep learning methods for sentiment analysis. They use the label dataset and train and test the model and short ....accuracy or f1 score. Nobody goes further and input the unlabeled data and "predict" the sentiment with their model. That is why I am wondering whether it is possible or not.

Thanks for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: Not a stack overflow question because no code. To answer your question nevertheless, it depends. If your headlines are also imdb movie reviews, then yes. If your headlines are business emails headlines, then no. A model trained on a specific domain is in most cases only viable for that domain. To generalize it further is possible but usually extensive work/data is required.

Answer (score 2):

Good question,

Yes, nothing stops you from testing it against your own dataset. However, this is not how this is supposed to be done:

Consider for example You train a model on Amazon reviews and then you are testing it on Movie reviews. So what's different? The distributions of data are different, this may have a lot of side effects. The choice of words, sentences, metaphors would be different in both the sets of reviews.

For eg. Consider this review in the **Life Sciences** domain:

"*This drug partially cures **cancer***"

This is most likely to output negative sentiment if you had trained on Amazon Review data because **cancer** is a negative word in other domains. So, there is a need to train different sentiment classifiers for different domains.

Summary:

1. Trying to Use Data from the same data source wherever possible.
2. Train and Predict on the same domain data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I understood it correctly that means, If I label some of my data (let's say 4000 out of 30,000) and train and test (validate) the model on this labeled data. Then I can predict the sentiments of the remaining 26,000 headlines? Is that right? If it is so, if possible, can you please suggest some resources?

Comment: Yes, you got me right. So, labelling 4000 data-points is a good idea to start with. So a couple of things you should always take care before labelling:
1. A positive sentiment could be expressed in different forms (or words). Try to find those examples which have different forms of the pos/neg sentiment.
2. This would help the model to generalize well within your corpus.

Also, there's no right number such as 4000 examples to plan the training stage. It all depends on the quality of the data. Maybe 1000 examples would be enough OR 18000 examples would still not be enough. #Experimentation